# Only alert() works in my jQuery for animating window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate my window scrolling immediately as my page loads. I tried putting an **alert()** for testing purposes and it worked... but only the **alert()** did.

***Javascript***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("jQuery is working!")
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop:$("#page5").offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: you forgot a semi-colon

Comment: Or maybe the element #page5  does not exist?

Comment: The code works fine when I test it. http://jsfiddle.net/kceu5erq/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot a semi-colon after your alert statement, which could be the reason.

Although it is not required but the browser might have implemented it that way.

**EDIT**: I tried executing the below code by omitting the semi-colon on chrome and it throws an error as `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`. After putting it back, it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("jQuery is working!")alert("not working")
});
```

**EDIT-2**: According to comments, it seems that the element you are trying to access does not exist on the page.

Comment: Although naturally recommended, semicolons at the end of lines is not required.

Comment: i think its not required in javascript.

Comment: yes i am aware of that. maybe the browser has decided not to execute it.

Comment: @Saksham: If you put two statements on the same line, the semicolon between them is required. On separate lines the semicolon is not required: http://jsfiddle.net/qyt4caan/

Comment: @Saksham Guffa is right.. its not required but It is considered as a good programming habit if you use it.